# greendao when does greenDao updates the database from session cache

Tags: android, greendao

The question is : When does GreenDao update the sql database from the session cache?

Let say that I'm querying an existing entity out of the database and than change one of it properties(fields). The changes are performed without directing the sql database in anyway.

So - should I do update on the entity?
When does GreenDao flush it's session cache into the database itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe sounds like JPA/Hibernate session cache. greenDAO doesn't have that. It is simpler. There are objects kept in memory and you always update them manually to the database.

Some more information (far from complete):
http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/sessions/

Comment: Do you mean with the "update" command? it is not a little bit wasteful to call it every change?

Comment: Yes, using someDao.update(entity). I don't know about your app and what it is doing. Maybe there is a more efficient way, maybe you should do some change tracking in a list yourself, and update the list in one transaction.

Comment: Well I thought about it but the problem is that the user might close the application in every second and I want to save his changed immediately in the database

Comment: That is what makes **greenDao** even more powerful ! What if the user makes lots of changes and then decides not to save ? All the changes are in memory (the objects) and not the database itself !

Answer (score 0):

When one generates the GreenDAO code (Entities, DAOs, DaoSession....etc), the DAOs by default extend the `AbstractDao` class which has a variety of methods for updating the database when needed instead of keeping the update in memory for a while such as (`update(T entity)`, `refresh(T entity)`, `updateInTrx(java.lang.Iterable entities)`).

For more information check the [AbstractDao javaDoc](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao/de/greenrobot/dao/AbstractDao.html)